# How to install safari 10 on Kubuntu 16.10?

Tags: kubuntu, wine, 16.10

How can I install Safari 10 (the latest version) on Ubuntu/ Kubuntu 16.10?

I am following this [guide](http://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/) trying to install wine 2 first but I got tone of error and it got wine 1.8 for me instead!

```
$ sudo apt remove wine* && sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/wine 
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install wine-stable
$ sudo apt install winetricks
```

So now whenever I run `sudo apt update` I get this error:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can fix this?

The Safari that it gives me by default is version 5 only:

[image]#

How can I get the version 10?

Also, how can I install Wine 2?

This is what I get:

```
$ wine --version
wine-1.8.5 (Ubuntu 1.8.5-1ubuntu2)
```

This is the entire outcome when I run `sudo apt update`:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnumdk/lollypop/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                  
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease [102 kB]                              
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                               
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu yakkety InRelease             
Hit:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x yakkety InRelease                         
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu yakkety InRelease     
Hit:9 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Get:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu yakkety InRelease  
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety Release
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en                                                                                                
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB                                                                                             
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                           
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                         
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                            
Ign:16 http:Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnumdk/lollypop/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                  
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease [102 kB]                              
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                               
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu yakkety InRelease             
Hit:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x yakkety InRelease                         
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu yakkety InRelease     
Hit:9 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Get:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu yakkety InRelease  
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety Release
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en                                                                                                
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB                                                                                             
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                           
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                         
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                            
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages                                                                                                  
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages                                                                                                 
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en                                                                                                
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB                                                                                             
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                             
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages                                                                                                   
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages                                                                                                  
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                 
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en                                                                                                 
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 306 kB in 31s (9,631 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.//ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all PackagesGet:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnumdk/lollypop/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                  
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease [102 kB]                              
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                               
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu yakkety InRelease             
Hit:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x yakkety InRelease                         
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu yakkety InRelease     
Hit:9 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Get:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu yakkety InRelease  
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety Release
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en                                                                                                
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB                                                                                             
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                           
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                         
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                            
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages                                                                                                  
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages                                                                                                 
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en                                                                                                
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB                                                                                             
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                             
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages                                                                                                   
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages                                                                                                  
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                 
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en                                                                                                 
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 306 kB in 31s (9,631 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch
```

And followed by the error above. It is all about `jonathonf/wine`!

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove that PPA. It doesn't have any packages for 16.10 (yakkety).

Comment: @dobey how do I remove that PPA?

Comment: Delete the file for it in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory. The filename should be obvious.